# WW1 German Postcard transcription

Tags: handwriting, writing

I have just found this postcard from some soldiers in Russia during WW1 and wonder if anyone can transcribe it for me.

[image]

Comment: Hello Jim and Welcome to german.SE! Do you mean transcribe, or also translate (into English, I guess)? While transcription of German handwriting-texts is a thing we do here, translation of individual texts is beyond the scope of german.SE.

Comment: Hey, I made a small edit, in order to make the question on-topic. Translators such as [Deepl](https://www.deepl.com/translator) do quite a good job at translating - even longer - texts.

Answer (score 6):

Geschrieben, den 26.8.17

Lieber Bruder!

Habe Deine liebe 
Karte erhalten was mich 
sehr gefreut hat und wofür 
ich Dir recht herzlich Danke. Wie 
ich daraus ersehen habe geht es 
Dir noch ganz gut was ich auch 
von mir noch schreiben kann. 
Dann hast Du mir geschrieben 
daß Du noch nicht weist wann 
Du Urlaub bekommst wann ich 
Urlaub bekomme weis ich 
auch noch nicht aber denke 
bis zum Oktober. Lieber Bruder 
hier schicke ich Dir das Bild von 
unserem Unterstand der in der 
mitte sitzt ist Jackob Hoffmann 
und mich wirst Du kennen 
L. Bruder Du wirst mir doch auch 
ein Bild schicken von Dir und 
Deinen Pferde sonst neues weis 
ich Dir nicht zu schreiben bin noch 
gesund und munter was ich auch 
von Dir hoffe

Es grüßt 
Dich herzlich 
Dein Bruder Hans Gruß Jakob Hoffmann

---

The last three lines are the sideways ones.
Some words are hard to decipher.
And he is skipping punctuation marks - I hope you can still get the idea.

A version with proper punctuation marks and spellings would be:

Geschrieben, den 26.8.17

Lieber Bruder!

Habe Deine liebe Karte erhalten, was mich sehr gefreut hat und wofür ich Dir recht herzlich Danke.
Wie ich daraus ersehen habe, geht es Dir noch ganz gut, was ich auch von mir noch schreiben kann.
Dann hast Du mir geschrieben, daß Du noch nicht weißt wann Du Urlaub bekommst.
Wann ich Urlaub bekomme, weiß ich auch noch nicht, aber denke bis zum Oktober.
Lieber Bruder, hier schicke ich Dir das Bild von unserem Unterstand.
Der in der Mitte sitzt ist Jakob Hoffmann und mich wirst Du kennen.
Lieber Bruder, Du wirst mir doch auch ein Bild schicken von Dir und Deinem Pferde.
Sonst Neues weiß ich Dir nicht zu schreiben.
Bin noch gesund und munter, was ich auch von Dir hoffe.

Es grüßt Dich herzlich
Dein Bruder Hans
Gruß Jakob Hoffmann

Comment: Use https://translate.google.com to produce a reasonable translation. First you will need to join up the lines like so ... " Lieber Bruder! Habe deine liebe Karte erhalten was mich sehr gefreut hat und wofür ich Dir recht herzlich Danke. ..."

Comment: "und mich wirst Du kennen"

Comment: aber denke [?][...] Oktober. => aber denke bis zum Oktober.

Comment: [...] weiß ich Dir nicht zu schreiben --> Sonst etwas[?] weiß ich Dir nicht zu schreiben

Comment: @infinitezero You're right about the "Geschrieben" - I was expecting the name of a city/village here - but thinking about it: since it was written during the war, the writer was maybe not allowed to reveal the exact position or didn't knew the name.

Comment: @Roland regarding "und mich wirst Du kennen": It makes sense, but I'm confused by the diacritics. Might be a mistake by the writer though.

Comment: @Roland Looking at it, I think it's "Sonst neues weiß ich Dir nicht zu schreiben"

Comment: Instead of Google translate, use [deepL](https://www.deepl.com/en/translator). It provides a much more sophisticated translation.

Comment: I've generally found that either deepL produces a translation identical to Google translate (and Google translate, of course, has background human checkers) or to produce (on average) a far worse translation.  *Perhaps* there is something specifically good about the deepL German->English ... but for anything else, Google.

Answer (score 2):

It's kind of difficult to read because of the handwriting but also because the contrast is kind of bad in some parts. At a glance, I don't see anything exciting. It's correspondence with his brother. Some pleasantries. He is sending a photograph showing himself and some other soldiers (one seems to be a relative) in front of a shelter. And he asks for a photograph of his brother and his brother's horse(?).

Comment: Erm, the rules here say „transcribing is fine, translating isn’t“. And this is imho way closer to a translation than what‘s within the margin of tolerance.

Comment: @Stephie This is not a translation. It's a synopsis. I was asked by a moderator to post this as an answer (and not a comment).